# How can I monitor Linux servers port usage using zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, linux, zabbix

How can i verify my linux server is currently used by anybody through ssh or any other port like 80. Any way to monitor this through zabbix ?

Thanks for the great help

Answer (score 1):

Use [UserParameter](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/user_parameters):

```
UserParameter=openssh.connections,/usr/bin/lsof -n -i :22 | grep ESTAB | wc -l
```